# Append List Object to Array

Tags: jquery, list, object, append, push

I am trying to append a list object to an array, and I'm having no luck. I'm a beginner at jQuery so any help and understanding is appreciated.

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  username = $("#user").val();
  group = $("#grouprole").val();
  role = $("#roleid").val();
  office = $("#office_id").val();
  lineyear = $("#lineyear_id").val();

  brandListArray = [];
  $.each();
  brandListObject = {
    category: $("#category_id" + z).val(),
    brand: $("#brand_id" + z).val(),
    plush: $("#plush_id" + z).val(),
    workload: $("#workload_id" + z).val()
  };

  brandListArray.push(brandListObject)
```

Comment: Would [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray) not work for you? It's a one-liner. If that doesn't help, please add the relevant `form` HTML to the question. An example of the array output you're trying to create would be useful too

Comment: Rory, could you give an example of where that would go in the code? Thank you!!

Comment: In your submit handler. `brandListArray = $(this).serializeArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I went with, should anyone else need something similar. Appreciate all the help and great responses.

```
     $("form").submit(function (event) {                
            event.preventDefault();                 

            username = $("#user" ).val();
            group    = $("#grouprole" ).val();
            role     = $("#roleid" ).val();
            office   = $("#office_id" ).val();
            lineyear = $("#lineyear_id" ).val();

            brandListArray = [];   //$(brandListObject).serializeArray();

            //LOOP    
            // create brandListObject for each j
            // push brandListObject to array
            for (j = 0;j<z;j++){
                brandListObject = {
                    category : $("#category_id"+j ).val(),
                    brand    : $("#brand_id"+j ).val(),
                    plush    : $("#plush_id"+j ).val(),
                    workload : $("#workload_id"+j ).val()                        
                }; 
                brandListArray.push(brandListObject);
            }ere
```